# In RLCraft, how do I create an Avian Soulstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In the hardcore Minecraft mod [RLCraft](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/rlcraft), there is apparently an item called the **Avian Soulstone**, which can bind avian mounts to you. I've recently tamed a [Ventoraptor](https://rlcraft.fandom.com/wiki/Ventoraptor), which is classified as an **Avian** by the RLCraft Lycanite bestiary.

[image]

I would therefore like to permanently bind my Ventoraptor to me with one of these Avian Soulstones.

However, I cannot find anywhere online how to craft these Avian Soulstones, and right-clicking it in the crafting menu gives no instructions or crafting directions.

There *are* crafting instructions for the [Soulstone](https://rlcraft.fandom.com/wiki/Soulstone), which has a wiki entry and a crafting recipe:

[image]

However, the Avian Soulstone does *not* have a wiki entry or instructions.

**How do I craft an Avian Soulstone in RLCraft?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. By watching this video:

It turns out that all you have to do is craft a regular **Soulstone,** with the recipe above, and then hold it in your hand and right click on the creature. It binds any creature to you. You don't need to craft the specific Soulstone type at all.